# How to start section numbering with title not section

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I am writing a book consisting of different chapters (each stored in an extra tex-file) and want to add numbers to each of the chapters' titles (MWE below). So for example, right now what my table of contents looks like is:

Chapter Title

1 Section Title

1.1 Subsection Title

2 Section Title

2.1 Subsection Title

But what I want it to look like is this:

1 Chapter Title

1.1 Section Title

1.1.1 Subsection Title

1.2 Section Title

1.2.1 Subsection Title

The structure of my project sort of looks like this:

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{standalone}
\input{preamble.tex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\input{Chapter1.tex}
\input{Chapter2.tex}
\end{document}
```

With the Chapters each having their own titles. Thanks in advance for your help, I hope it became clear what I'm trying to achieve, please feel free to correct me if I'm doing something wrong as I am still pretty new to this platform.

Comment: A warm welcome!! Please include a MWE including everything prior to `\begin{document}` 
  https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: What you want is the default. You are changing the default and asking it how to get the default back. Preparing a minimal working example will show you what to change.

Comment: Is there something like `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{}`?

Comment: @Johannes_B: Can you clarify? I think the default is that the numbering starts at section level. I need it to start at 'title-level'.

Comment: Please run the following 6 line example -=> https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports#Setting_up_a_document

Comment: I updated the MWE... The document class I have to use doesn't define chapters, its a customized class file by the book's publisher.

Comment: Note that Springer probably doesn't want you to change the numbering defaults, if you want to publish with them - if you don't want to publish with them, you can choose another documentclass with different numbering (such as `report`).