# How can I let the section numbering start with 1.1 instead of 1?

Tags: numbering

my question is very simple: I want the section numbering in my table of contents to start with 1.1 instead of simply 1 (and the subsections to start with 1.1.1 for example). Is there a counter or anything like that (maybe a possibility to renew the command without changing the format of the section headings?) to simply change this? I am using the Springer template which uses article-like sections.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Could you provide a small sample document using that shows what you're doing. It should be compilable and use the document class you are using.

Comment: Isn't this the same question posted again? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/423027/how-to-start-section-numbering-with-title-not-section  You should, instead of posting again, edit your original question to make it clearer or more attractive to answers.

Comment: Also, do you want the first 1 in 1.1 to be a different counter?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach I can think of is to use the `report` document class and set the chapter number to be one.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\section{Foo}
\subsection{bar}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But if I understand the question correctly (and it's admittedly not very clear), the document has chapters but the TOC is only supposed to display subsections and below. (And one of the Springer classes is being used.)

Comment: @AlanMunn Ah, I see. I missed the mention of the Springer template.